# Display Custom Post Type in divs just thumb and title

Tags: custom-post-types

The Thing is that i was trying to Display only the thumb and the title of the post inside the thumb with a "got to this Portfolio" button.
Something like this:

```
    <section>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <div class="row">
            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
                    echo '<h4>';
                    the_title();
                    echo '</h4>';
                    // The Thumb
                    echo '</div>';
                endwhile;
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and yeah the h4 is not showing and idk why...

the other Thing that the thumb support for the custom type is not showing inside the WordPress admin Panel here is the functions.php Code:

```
    /* Custom Post Type Start */

    function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    // CPT Options

    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'portfolio' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'portfolio' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
    )
    );
    }
        // Hooking up our function to theme setup
    add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

    /* Custom Post Type End */

    /*Custom Post type start*/

function cw_post_type_portfolio() {

    $supports = array(
    'title', // post title
    'editor', // post content
    'author', // post author
    'thumbnail', // featured images
    'excerpt', // post excerpt
    'custom-fields', // custom fields
    'comments', // post comments
    'revisions', // post revisions
    'post-formats', // post formats
    );

    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('portfolio', 'plural'),
    'singular_name' => _x('portfolio', 'singular'),
    'menu_name' => _x('portfolio', 'admin menu'),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x('portfolio', 'admin bar'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New portfolio'),
    'new_item' => __('New portfolio'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit portfolio'),
    'view_item' => __('View portfolio'),
    'all_items' => __('All portfolio'),
    'search_items' => __('Search portfolio'),
    'not_found' => __('No portfolio found.'),
    );

    $args = array(
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    );
    register_post_type('portfolio', $args);
    }
    add_action('init', 'cw_post_type_portfolio');

    /*Custom Post type end*/
```

[image]

Comment: why are you creating the posttype 2x?  lot's of issues here...gimme a minute

Comment: oh didnt saw that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erase all the code above from your functions.php and use this:

```
function cw_post_type_portfolio() {

  $supports = array(
    'title', // post title
    'editor', // post content
    'author', // post author
    'thumbnail', // featured images
    'excerpt', // post excerpt
    'custom-fields', // custom fields
    'comments', // post comments
    'revisions', // post revisions
    'post-formats', // post formats
  );

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('portfolios', 'plural'),
    'singular_name' => _x('portfolio', 'singular'),
    'menu_name' => _x('portfolio', 'admin menu'),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x('portfolio', 'admin bar'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New portfolio'),
    'new_item' => __('New portfolio'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit portfolio'),
    'view_item' => __('View portfolio'),
    'all_items' => __('All portfolios'),
    'search_items' => __('Search portfolios'),
    'not_found' => __('No portfolios found.'),
  );

  $args = array(
    'supports' => $supports,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
  );
  register_post_type('mla_portfolio', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'cw_post_type_portfolio');

/*Custom Post type end*/
```

I've edited a few lines including removing duplication issues and using the actual $supports array which wasn't included in the function call.  I've also changed your posttype from plain portfolio to mla_portfolio so you'll need to change the code for your wp_query to the correct reference.

The reason your h4 isn't working is because you used `the_title()` instead of `get_the_title()`.

*UPDATE*

added query code:

```
<section>
    <div class="portfolio">
        <div class="row">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'mla_portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
                  echo '<h4>'.get_the_title().'</h4>';
                  echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: updated to add reference to the h4 issue

Comment: okay added your wp_query code and updated the functions.php one more time because you didn't pluralize your cpt name where needed.  that should do it.

Comment: thank you a lot :D but the thumb Option is still not showing in the admin Panel... i really dont know why cause i added everything now like you posted it..

Comment: Can you go to settings/permalinks to refresh everything?  I just tried on my site and it's working.

Comment: allready did it but still not showing

Comment: just out of curiousity.  Can you click screen options on the top right of the cpt edit page and make sure featured image is checked?

Comment: i realized that there is not featured Image Option to check or uncheck

Comment: make sure that the code is completely erased except for mine.  did you add it anywhere else that may be causing conflicts?

Comment: everything is there like in your updated Version...

Comment: is everything else in the supports array showing up?

Comment: yes everything else is showing up. tested the WordPress standart themes and i can see there the featured Image but when i try my own theme the featured Image Option is not there

Comment: updated your answer

Comment: what theme are you using?